# Next.js 500 error and Axios error when calling API that uses environment variables

Tags: api, next.js, environment-variables

I'm building a wine pairing app in Next.js—where when a user clicks on a type of wine (i.e. chardonnay), it calls an API to return the suggested food pairings. This works with no issue when I use NEXT_PUBLIC for my environment variables, but I don't want to expose my private API key.

This is my first time using server-side environment variables with Next.js I understand that this needs to happen within the `pages/api` folder. API routing with Next.js is still something that I'm learning, so I've been following the docs, and I also found [this tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/12/protect-api-key-production-nextjs-api-route/) which I followed that resulted in the `500 (Internal Server Error)`. I'm also getting an Axios error. This is a screenshot of both errors—please let me know if anything should be expanded, and I'll post another screenshot.

[image: error message screenshot]

I also understand that I can use `getStaticProps()`, but this call is coming from a component rather than a page, and I understand from the docs that `getStaticProps()` must be called from a page.

This is what my `.env.local` looks like:

```
API_KEY=<my api key>
BASE_URL=https://api.spoonacular.com/
```

This is what my API call looks like (`pages/api/wineWithFood.js`)

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default async function wineWithFood(req, res) {
  const {
    query: { wine },
  } = req;

  const url = `${process.env.BASE_URL}food/wine/dishes?wine=${wine}&apiKey=${process.env.API_KEY}`;

  const response = await axios.get(url);
  res.status(200).json({
    data: response.data,
  });
}
```

This is the relevant code for what that call looks like in my component which is properly imported into the page where it belongs:

```
const getPairing = async () => {
    axios.get(`/api/wineWithFood?wine=${wine}`, {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response)
      .then((response) => {
      setData(response.data.pairings)
      })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }

const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setWine(e.target.value);
    getPairing();
  };

console.log(wine)
```

I see that the request isn't capturing the wine type, but when I `console.log` the wine, it's showing up in the browser console as expected. When I `console.log` the `response.data` from the API call, I get a status code of 400 with a message stating that the wine must not be empty.

Now, if I change my code to the following—I get the same errors and `console.log`s as I mentioned... but ***only*** on the first try! On the second try (clicking the same exact wine), the wine shows correctly in the browser console since I'm `console.log`ing it, but I get that same 500 error in my console, however, now I can see all of the correct data in my terminal! That leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong on the frontend. Here's the tweaked code that results in this:

```
const getPairing = async (wine) => {
    axios
      .get(`/api/wineWithFood?wine=${wine}`, {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
      })
      .then((response) => response)
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data.pairings);
        console.log(response.data.pairings);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setWine(e.target.value);

    getPairing(wine);
  };
```

I'm happy to check out any other resources to help me out if that's a better answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out and wanted to share the answer—which was staring me in the face.

I left my API call in `pages/api/wineWithFood.js` the same. I was right. The error was on the frontend. I got rid of the `getPairing()` function and put everything in the `handleChange` function. When I console logged my response on the frontend, I realized that the info I needed was `res.data.data.pairings`. I also changed the axios call by using `e.target.value` as the search query. I removed `wine` and `setWine` since it wasn't necessary. Here's the final code:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .get(`/api/wineWithFood?wine=${e.target.value}`, {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data.data.pairings);
      });
  };
```

I hope this can help someone out—also I'm open to feedback if there's a better way.